# .net receives connection error after oracle db is taken down and restarted

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Our dev oracle db gets taken down each night so that database changes can be applied. It is then restarted but the first connection made from a .net web app then next day fails with the following error

```
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel Process ID: 28303 Session ID: 22 Serial number: 303
```

Any subsequent connections work fine though.

Is there anything we can do to prevent this issue?

Comment: Have you looked in the oracle logs to see the detail of the error?  There could be quite a few different things causing it and the logs will give you more info on where to start looking.

Comment: To be honest I am not overly familiar with Oracle, are the logs on available through Oracle Sql Developer?

Comment: It has been a while since I've dealt with oracle.  They should be in the home directory for the instance giving the problem.   You will need an oracle log reader.  take a look at this link http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49682/ora-03113-end-of-file-on-communication-channel-on-startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be expected behaviour.  Your app is trying to connect and it fails because the connection was lost.

It would not be uncommon to capture this particular connection, pause for a few seconds and then try to reconnect before you would log it as an error.

You might schedule that your web app pool would be restarted shortly after the database changes are made as well.

Comment: Thanks, this does appear to be the issue as far as we can tell.